# Secure Nginx Directory But Not Files

Tags: nginx

**Is there a way to require authentication to view directory listings but still allow public access to the files without authentication?**

Using the sample code:

```
location / {
  auth_basic           "closed site";
  auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;
  autoindex on;
}
```

Requires authentication on both files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work or not, but try it and tell me if it works.

```
location ~ /$ {
  auth_basic "closed site";
  auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;
  autoindex on;
}
location / {
  try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but all I get is a blank page (probably a 404 Not found) although the files are accessible by direct link. The location is in a subdirectory so I used `location ~ /files/$`.

Comment: Error log: `[error] 22820#0: *35 open() "/[directory to website root (no trailing slash)]404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ..., server: www.website.com, request: "GET /files HTTP/1.1", host: "website.com"` Also, the server is not asking for authentication anymore.